# Show the table only when I looked for 3 characters

Tags: angular, filter, angular-material, mat-table

I work with angular, angular-material and firebase.

I can correctly display my data, filter, sort and paginate them with the code below.

By cons I would display my data only when I have already entered 3 characters in my search bar.

Can you help me or give me a track? Thank you !

```
export class AnnuairePSComponent implements OnInit {

Data = {
titre:'',
prenom: '',
nom:'',
prof: '',
sv: '',
site:''
}

displayedColumns = [
'titre',
'prenom',
'nom',
'prof',
'sv',
'site'
 ];

 dataSource = new MatTableDataSource();

applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
filterValue = filterValue.trim(); 
filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); 
this.dataSource.filter = filterValue;
}

ngAfterViewInit() {
this.psService.getpss().subscribe(res => {this.dataSource.data = res;}); 
}

private paginator: MatPaginator;
private sort: MatSort;

@ViewChild(MatSort) set matSort(ms: MatSort) {
this.sort = ms;
this.setDataSourceAttributes();
}

@ViewChild(MatPaginator) set matPaginator(mp: MatPaginator) {
this.paginator = mp;
this.setDataSourceAttributes();
}

setDataSourceAttributes() {
this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
}

constructor(private psService: PsService, private router: Router) { }
}
```

html

```
<mat-toolbar color="primary" [ngStyle]="{'height': '120px','padding-top' :'30px'}"> 

<mat-form-field appearance="outline" style="width:100%" >
<input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value)"  >
<mat-label>Rechercher un professionel</mat-label>
</mat-form-field>

<span class="example-spacer"></span>
</mat-toolbar>

<mat-card [ngStyle]="{'margin': '5px'}" *ngIf="dataSource?.filteredData.length">

<mat-table  [dataSource]="dataSource" [ngStyle]="{ 'width':'100%'}" matSort>
.....
</mat-table>
```

Comment: Do you want to be able to filter only when 3 or more characters entered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Did you try :

```
applyFilter(filterValue: string) {
    if (filterValue.length > 3) {
        filterValue = filterValue.trim(); 
        filterValue = filterValue.toLowerCase(); 
        this.dataSource.filter = filterValue; 
    }
}
```

Edit : ok so you should register your input in a local variable in your template :

```
 <input matInput (keyup)="applyFilter($event.target.value);" #filterInput >
```

and then apply a structural directive on your table :

```
<mat-table  [dataSource]="dataSource" [ngStyle]="{ 'width':'100%'}" matSort *ngIf="filterInput.value.length > 3">
```

Comment: my table is still visible when loading the component. Should I modify some things in the html?

Comment: Ok my bad, I did not understand it that way. I just updated my answer.